flatpak error: Unable to allocate instance id
How to resolve a flatpak error error: Unable to allocate instance id?
This error happens for various flatpak apps, and one solution recommended is to reboot the computer. However, this does not always work. Are there any other solutions that could make a flatpak app runnable?

Try prefixing the command with dbus-run-session:
dbus-run-session flatpak run my.flatpak.app.name

I've had this problem with verso-browser and activating a d-bus service for that app worked for me. (This can happen if you e.g. didn't have d-bus running properly before.)
